# What is the difference between creating different animateColorAsState function vs a single updateTransition function?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Here is a function is which I create 2 different `animationAsState` function.

```
@Composable
fun AnimateAsStateDemo1() {
    var boxState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val color by animateColorAsState(
        targetValue = if (boxState) Color.Blue else Color.Red,
    )

    val size by animateDpAsState(targetValue = if (boxState) 100.dp else 50.dp)


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(size = size)
            .background(color = color)
            .clickable {
                boxState = !boxState
            }
    )
}
```

Here I create a single `updateTransition` transition to achieve the same result.

```
@Composable
fun AnimateAsStateDemo2() {
    var boxState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val transition = updateTransition(targetState = boxState, label = "")
    val color by transition.animateColor(label = "") { state ->
        when (state) {
            true -> Color.Blue
            false -> Color.Red
        }
    }


    val size by transition.animateDp(label = "") { state ->
        when (state) {
            true -> 100.dp
            false -> 50.dp
        }

    }


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(size = size)
            .background(color = color)
            .clickable {
                boxState = !boxState
            }
    )
}
```

They both achieve the same result.

Is the second approach superior to the first approach? If so why?